# choosing a control as the *absence* of a condition in a retrospective longitudinal study

Tags: experiment-design, control-group

Let's say I am interested in cancer patients (or any other disease), and I am looking at their behavior prior to cancer onset - in a retrospective, longitudinal study.
Now I want to design a control group. Let's say I am collecting patients from the same medical institute who didn't have cancer. But what do I look for? Their behavior prior to WHAT DATE? And if I want to match on age, then WHICH AGE?

In other words, how to look at time-related characteristics for the control group, when there is no specific point in time (like the onset of the disease) to compare to?

Comment: How will you know which patients will get cancer? Given that you are looking at their behavior prior to cancer onset?

Comment: @user2974951 see edits. This is a retrospective longitudinal study. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a cancer researcher, so these are just ideas to get you thinking:// If you're trying to find 'fake twins', maybe try to match for some combination of age, race, profession, socioeconomic class. The more characteristics, the harder it will be to find matches. // If you have a theory as to what might be important, then pick a control group that you hope won't get whatever kind of cancer is of interest, otherwise random. // Look at former studies that led to interesting results and try to emulate methods of selecting control group.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for your suggestions. I know how to do the matching on static things like gender and background diseases (by the way this has nothing to do with cancer, I just gave it as an example). My main problem is how to find time-related characteristics (like age and former behavior) when there is not reference point in time. When the disease is present, you can talk about a point in time which is the onset. But what are the time frames when there is no such thing?